# Creating objects with very many optional fields

Tags: oop, architecture, field, performance

I'm trying to recreate Hearthstone cards as objects in Java, but I'm having trouble doing this in a good and efficient way.

All cards have some common properties like a 'name'. But the problem is that there is about 300 cards to generate, and there is about 30 different abilities that each card may or may not have. Now, do I have to create a basic card class with all the possible abilities set to false and then set all its specific ability parameters to true? This approach seems to get very messy with all the getters and all the extra information that some abilities needs to specify... So my question is if there's there a better way to solve this kind of problem?

I would like to create these card objects so that I'm only 'adding' the specific abilities as fields, but I can't figure out how to do this in a good way.

Thankful for help!

Comment: It's difficult to provide any answers without more concrete information, but one way would be to have an `Ability` class (or whatever) and each card would have a collection of only relevant instances.

Comment: Ok, so then I could create each ability as an object in-itself and add to that list? That's a good idea, thanks :)

Comment: It's an option. You could also use an enum, etc. It depends on what you actually need "abilities" to be.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dave said, it's a little difficult to be sure what the best solution to your problem is without more context. However, from what I can gather, your problem is a pretty common one. For common problems, programmers often create efficient solutions that can be used over and over again called [design patterns](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-design-patterns--net-12752).

Design patterns aren't needed in every case, so be careful not to overuse them, but it seems like they could help you here. Both solutions mentioned by Dave may work, but the problem with making each ability an object is that it requires you to make as many classes as you have abilities. Furthermore, if each ability is a simple variable, it may be overkill to create classes for all of them, particularly since so many classes can become difficult to maintain. Although having these abilities inherit from an interface somewhat helps with maintainability, I think an easier solution can probably be found in the builder pattern.

I won't explain it in detail here, but here's a [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) that seems reasonably simple. It's basic purpose is to

For your particular example it would look something like this:

```
    public class Card

    {

        private final String name;
        private final Ability soundAbility;
        private final Ability animationAbility;
        private final Ability customMessageAbility;
        private final String technology;

        // The constructor is private in this case to restrict instantiation to the builder.
        private Card(CardBuilder builder)
        {
            this.name = builder.name;
            this.soundAbility = builder.soundAbility;
            this.animationAbility = builder.animationAbility;
            this.customMessageAbility = builder.customMessageAbility;
            this.technology = builder.technology;
        }

        // Getters
        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public Ability getSoundAbility()
        {
            return this.soundAbility;
        }

        // ... More getters and stuff ...

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            String text = "";
            text += this.name + ":";
            text += "\n\t" + this.soundAbility;
            text += "\n\t" + this.animationAbility;
            text += "\n\t" + this.customMessageAbility;
            text += "\n\tI have the ability of " + this.technology + "!";
            return text;
        }

        // Nested builder class
        public static class CardBuilder
        {

            private final String name;
            private Ability soundAbility;
            private Ability animationAbility;
            private Ability customMessageAbility;
            private String technology;

            public CardBuilder(String name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public CardBuilder soundAbility(Ability soundAbility)
            {
                this.soundAbility = soundAbility;
                return this;
            }

            public CardBuilder animationAbility(Ability animationAbility)
            {
                this.animationAbility = animationAbility;
                return this;
            }

            public CardBuilder customMessageAbility(Ability customMessageAbility)
            {
                this.customMessageAbility = customMessageAbility;
                return this;
            }

            public CardBuilder technology(String technology)
            {
                this.technology = technology;
                return this;
            }

            public Card build()
            {
                return new Card(this);
            }

        }

    }
```

Then to run the program:

```
package builderTest;

class BuilderMain
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Initialize ability objects.
        Ability a1 = new SoundAbility();
        Ability a2 = new AnimationAbility();
        Ability a3 = new CustomMessageAbility();

        // Build card
        Card card = new Card.CardBuilder("Birthday Card")
            .soundAbility(a1)
            .animationAbility(a2)
            .customMessageAbility(a3)
            .technology("Flash")
            .build();

        System.out.println(card);
    }

}
```

The output would be something along the lines of:

```
Birthday Card:
    I have the ability of sound!
    I have the ability of animation!
    I have the ability of customizing messages!
    I have the ability of Flash!
```

Keep in mind that I'm working without much context, so what you need might be significantly different.

Answer (score -1):

Although previous answers are very good, there is still another way of achieve this Object creation

> with very many optional fields

I found myself in similar situation when dealing with DB complexity and [Command design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern). As you know some table columns values are mandatory - some are not. I'm using this [Effective Java book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)
for such cases.

So, useful here is the `Consider a builder when faced with many constructor parameters`. By doing so, you avoid

- first, the *Telescoping constructor pattern* (does not scale well) - it works, but it is hard to write client code when there are many parameters, and harder still to read it.
- second, the *JavaBeans Pattern*, which is good, but allows inconsistency and mandates mutability. It may be in an inconsistent state partway through its construction and precludes the possibility of making a class immutable too.

The Builder pattern as used simulates named optional parameters as found in Ada and Python.Like a constructor, a builder can impose invariants on its parameters. But it is **critical** that they be checked after copying the parameters from the builder to the object, and that they be checked on
the object fields rather than the builder fields.

Cheers.